# Dynamic Sizing of UITableViewCell: within its UITableView row

Tags: swift, uitableview

I noticed that the UITableView's row height doesn't match the cell's height.

[image]

I want to be able to control the cell's height via the UITableView's row height.

As you can see, the cell apparently overlays the UITableView without regard to the row height.

[image]

**Question:**  How do I fit the 'Hello' cell within the lines of the UITableView?  
 I can adjust the lines, but it has no effect on the cell.

Answer (score 0):

> want to be able to control the cell's height via the UITableView's row height.

Uncheck Automatic and increase the Row Height.

Comment: I tried that, has no effect.   I can play with the row heights.... but it doesn't effect the cell that is inserted in the row via the UITableViewDataSource.  They appear to be INDEPENDENT of each other, rather than DEPENDENT (which I want).

Comment: Yes it does. That is exactly how fixed row height is determined.  If not, you are turning it off in your code.

Comment: Apparently the culprit is 'the estimatedHeightForRowAt' UITableViewDelegate.   Removing it allowed me to work Automatic or Manual Row Height in sync with the UITableViewCell.

Comment: Correct, as soon as you set the estimated height, that is a signal that you want to opt into "self-sizing cells" (automatic height). So what I said was correct; you were turning off fixed row height in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The apparent solution is to remove the UITableViewDelegate's ...estimatedHeight...
method:

[image]

Result:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.rowHeight = 40
        // ...
    }
```

Result:
[image]